# Random Forests and ROC Curves in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, julia, random-forest, decision-tree, roc

I'm using the ScikitLearn flavour of the [DecisionTree.jl](https://github.com/bensadeghi/DecisionTree.jl) package to create a random forest model for a binary classification problem of one of the [RDatasets](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/RDatasets.jl) data sets (see bottom of the DecisionTree.jl home page for what I mean by ScikitLearn flavour). I'm also using the [MLBase](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MLBase.jl) package for model evaluation.

I have built a random forest model of my data and would like to create a ROC Curve for this model. Reading the documentation available, I do understand what a ROC curve is in theory. I just can't figure out how to create one for a specific model.

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) the last part of the first sentence that I have marked in bold italics below is the one that is causing my confusion: "In statistics, a receiver operating characteristic (ROC), or ROC curve, is a graphical plot that illustrates the performance of a binary classifier system ***as its discrimination threshold is varied***." There is more on the threshold value throughout the article but this still confuses me for binary classification problems. What is the threshold value and how do I vary it?

Also, in the [MLBase documentation on ROC Curves](http://mlbasejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/perfeval.html#receiver-operating-characteristics-roc) it says "Compute an ROC instance or an ROC curve (a vector of ROC instances), based on given scores and a threshold thres." But doesn't mention this threshold anywhere else really.

Example code for my project is given below. Basically, I want to create a ROC curve for the random forest but I'm not sure how to or if it's even appropriate.

```
using DecisionTree
using RDatasets
using MLBase

quakes_data = dataset("datasets", "quakes");

# Add in a binary column as feature column for classification
quakes_data[:MagGT5] = convert(Array{Int32,1}, quakes_data[:Mag] .> 5.0)

# Getting features and labels where label = 1 is mag > 1 and label = 2 is mag <= 5
features = convert(Array, quakes_data[:, [1:3;5]]);
labels = convert(Array, quakes_data[:, 6]);
labels[labels.==0] = 2

# Create a random forest model with the tuning parameters I want
r_f_model = RandomForestClassifier(nsubfeatures = 3, ntrees = 50, partialsampling=0.7, maxdepth = 4)

# Train the model in-place on the dataset (there isn't a fit function without the in-place functionality)
DecisionTree.fit!(r_f_model, features, labels)

# Apply the trained model to the test features data set (here I haven't partitioned into training and test)
r_f_prediction = convert(Array{Int64,1}, DecisionTree.predict(r_f_model, features))

# Applying the model to the training set and looking at model stats
TrainingROC = roc(labels, r_f_prediction) #getting the stats around the model applied to the train set
#     p::T    # positive in ground-truth
#     n::T    # negative in ground-truth
#     tp::T   # correct positive prediction
#     tn::T   # correct negative prediction
#     fp::T   # (incorrect) positive prediction when ground-truth is negative
#     fn::T   # (incorrect) negative prediction when ground-truth is positive
```

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972736/plotting-a-roc-curve-from-a-random-forest-classification) question and didn't find it helpful really.

Answer (score 4):

The task in binary classification is to give a `0`/`1` (or `true`/`false`, `red`/`blue`) label to a new, unlabeled, data-point. Most classification algorithms are designed to output a continuous real value. This value is optimized to be higher for points with known or predicted label `1`, and lower for points with known or predicted label `0`. To use this value to generate a `0`/`1` prediction, an additional *threshold* is used. Points with a value higher than threshold are predicted to be labeled `1` (and for lower than threshold a `0` label is predicted ).

Why is this setup useful? Because, sometimes mispredicting a `0` instead of a `1` is more costly, and then you can set the threshold low, making the algorithm output predict `1`s more often.

In an extreme case when predicting `0` instead of a `1` costs nothing for the application, you can set the threshold at infinity, making it always output `0` (which is obviously the best solution, since it incurs no cost).

The threshold trick cannot eliminate errors from the classifier - no classifier in real-world problems is perfect or free from noise. What it can do is change the ratio between the `0`-when-really-`1` errors and `1`-when-really-`0` errors for the final classification.

As you increase the threshold, more points are classified with a `0` label. Consider a chart with the fraction of points classified with `0` on the x-axis, and the fraction of points with a `0`-when-really-`1` error on the y-axis. For each value of the threshold, plot a point for the resulting classifier on this chart. Plotting a point for all thresholds you get a curve. This is (some variant of) the ROC curve, which summarizes the abilities of the classifier. An often used metric for quality of classification is the AUC or area-under-curve of this chart, but in fact, the whole curve can be of interest in applications.

A summary like this appears in many texts on machine learning, which are a google query away.

Hope this clarifies the role of the *threshold* and its relation to ROC curves.

Comment: Thanks, I had read many texts and they didn't give me as clear an understanding as you just have.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your code, the last line `roc(labels...)` gives a single point of the ROC curve for the specific predictions of the DecisionTree `r_f_model`. This DecisionTree algorithm is an example of a classifier which does not output a real number, but an actual prediction. Perhaps some parameters in the fitting function can generate more points to flesh out the ROC curve.